# Javascript Rest Params missing

Tags: javascript, express, rest-parameters

```
const Router = {
  get: (path, ...rest) => {
   console.log(rest)
  }
}
```

```
import router from '../shared/router';
router.get('/tester/123', someMiddleware, 'HomeController#index');
```

the function shows a `f(path)` with no rest params??

If I change it to ..

```
    const Router = {
      get: (path, second) => {
       console.log(rest)
      }
    }
```

Second will show up..
`f(path, second)`

It's like rest params are getting removed. Why is this?

Comment: By `the function shows a f(path) with no rest params??`, what do you mean "shows"? Are you referring to a particular IDE with odd intellisense?

Comment: `If I change it to` ... then `rest` will be undefined since it's not defined

Comment: Rest parameters are always considered optional if that's what you're asking about?

Comment: By show, I mean chrome inspector. No, I mean if I change it a regular arg it works. Rest arg it is missing.